# Update hash value in DOM when onchange event fired using javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, hash, attributes, onchange

I have content in two tabbed views list and grid. The content includes pagination links with a hash value of #list or #grid depending on the tabbed view. Default is #list. When the tabbed view switches to grid I want to update the hash value on pagination links from #list to #grid on anchors with a class name of '.pagehash'. How do I do that with javascript/jquery? Here's what I have so far:

```
<a href="?{{ query }}&cfilters={{count}}&page={{ results.currentPage-1 }}#list" class="pagehash">&larr; Prev</a>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#view-tabs').on('change.zf.tabs', function() {
    $(".pagehash").attr('href').replace(/^.*?(#|$)/,location.hash); // doesn't work when tabs change from list -> grid
    console.log(location.hash); // works when tabs change fom list -> grid
});
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help greatly appreciated. Searched stack overflow and google for the answer. Nothing has turned up.

Answer (score 0):

OK so seems I've answered this myself. Added comments in the code but basically we're getting the current raw hash value without the # symbol then iterating through each instance of pagination links with a class of .pagehash and replacing the current hash with the new hash when view switches from list -> grid or grid -> list:

```
<script>
$('#view-tabs').on('change.zf.tabs', function() {
    // Get the raw hash value
    var getHash = location.hash.split('#')[1];
    // For EACH link that has a class of pagehash replace current hash value with hash symbol and raw hash value
    $('.pagehash').each(function() {
        var getLink = $(this).attr('href').replace(/\#.*/, '#'+getHash);
        $(this).attr('href', getLink);
    });
});
</script>
```